# Swift OSX - Unrecognized selector sent to instance on NSObject Subclass when setting value

Tags: swift, macos, nsobject

I am trying to populate an array of NSObject custom class but when I insert the data I receive an error: `[Wood_Factory___Gerenciador.FotoProduto setFoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000055a0`

Action that calls the class

```
@IBAction func selecionarFotosButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {

        let panel = NSOpenPanel()
        panel.canChooseFiles = true
        panel.canChooseDirectories = false
        panel.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        panel.canCreateDirectories = false
        panel.allowedFileTypes = NSImage.imageTypes

        panel.beginSheetModal(for: view.window!) { (result) in

            if result.rawValue == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
                for url in panel.urls {
                    let fotoNSImage = NSImage(byReferencing: url)
                    let fotoNSImageRedim = Ferramentas.redimensionaNSImage(imagem: fotoNSImage, tamanho: NSSize(width: 200, height: 200))
                    let fotoNSImageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(data: (fotoNSImageRedim.tiffRepresentation)!)
                    let fotoNSImagePng = fotoNSImageRep?.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.png, properties: [:])

                    //let fotoProduto = FotoProduto(foto: PFFile(data: fotoNSImagePng!)!, categorias: [])
                    let fotoProduto = FotoProduto()
                    fotoProduto.foto = PFFile(data: fotoNSImagePng!)
                    fotoProduto.categorias = []
                    fotoProduto.imagemCapa = false

                    self.projeto?.fotos = [FotoProduto]()
                    self.projeto?.fotos.append(fotoProduto)
                }

                self.verificaCapaDefinida()

                if !self.capaDefinida {
                    let indiceImagem = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

                    self.definirImagemCapa(indice: indiceImagem, limparSelecao: true)
                } else {
                    self.fotosProjetoCollectionView.deselectAll(self)
                    self.fotosProjetoCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

FotoProduto Class

```
import Cocoa

import Parse

class FotoProduto: NSObject {

    @NSManaged var foto: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var categorias: [String]
    @NSManaged var imagemCapa: Bool

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Here is the complete error:

> 2017-09-21 07:13:58.074278-0400 Wood Factory -
>   Gerenciador[1241:101761] -[Wood_Factory___Gerenciador.FotoProduto
>   setFoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000055a0
>   2017-09-21 07:13:58.478223-0400 Wood Factory -
>   Gerenciador[1241:101761] [General]
>   -[Wood_Factory___Gerenciador.FotoProduto setFoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080000055a0 2017-09-21
>   07:13:58.482745-0400 Wood Factory - Gerenciador[1241:101761] [General]
>   (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff930452cb
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 171   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffa7e5d48d objc_exception_throw + 48    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00007fff930c6f04 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92fb7755
>   ___forwarding_** + 1061   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff92fb72a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   Wood Factory -
>   Gerenciador          0x000000010003e68c
>   _T026Wood_Factory___Gerenciador30GerenciarProjetoViewControllerC28selecionarFotosButtonClickedySo8NSButtonCFySo13NSApplicationC13ModalResponseVcfU_
>   + 1948    6   Wood Factory - Gerenciador          0x000000010003ee78 _T026Wood_Factory___Gerenciador30GerenciarProjetoViewControllerC28selecionarFotosButtonClickedySo8NSButtonCFySo13NSApplicationC13ModalResponseVcfU_TA
>   + 88  7   Wood Factory - Gerenciador          0x000000010000ba01 _T0So13NSApplicationC13ModalResponseVIxy_ADIyBy_TR + 49  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff911b78b9 -[NSSavePanel _didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:]
>   + 95  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff90d25b84 -[NSWindow _endWindowBlockingModalSession:returnCode:] + 308     10  AppKit                              0x00007fff911ba073 -[NSSavePanel
>   ok:] + 461    11  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffa89753a7
>   _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53   12  AppKit                              0x00007fff91232721 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] +
>   456   13  AppKit                              0x00007fff90d16cc4
>   -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff90d16bec __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 136
>     15  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffa89753a7
>   _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53   16  AppKit                              0x00007fff90d16b44 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 128     17  AppKit
>   0x00007fff90d59539 -[NSButtonCell _sendActionFrom:] + 98  18 
>   libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fffa89753a7
>   _os_activity_initiate_impl + 53   19  AppKit                              0x00007fff90d15426 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] +
>   2481  20  AppKit                              0x00007fff90d59272
>   -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 798  21  AppKit                              0x00007fff90d13ddb -[NSControl
>   mouseDown:] + 832     22  AppKit
>   0x00007fff913ae24f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting)
>   _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6341     23  AppKit                              0x00007fff913aaa6c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting)
>   _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 1942  24  AppKit                              0x00007fff913a9f0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541     25 
>   AppKit                              0x00007fff9122e681
>   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145   26  AppKit                              0x00007fff90aa9427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002  27  AppKit
>   0x00007fff90a73e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237   28  Wood Factory -
>   Gerenciador          0x000000010005038d main + 13     29  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00007fffa8743235 start + 1 )

Comment: You are using CoreData?

Comment: No, I am not using CoreData

Comment: Isn't `@NSManaged` for `NSManagedObject` (for CoreData)?

Comment: But I am not using CoreData, how can I define the class to be read bu Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was create a subclass of PFObject.

```
import Cocoa

import Parse

class FotoProduto: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    @NSManaged var foto: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var categorias: [String]
    @NSManaged var imagemCapa: Bool

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(foto: PFFile, categorias: [String]) {
        super.init()

        self.foto = foto
        self.categorias = categorias
        self.imagemCapa = false
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "FotoProduto"
    }
}
```